# Node Voltages by Loop analysis?

Tags: circuit-analysis

As generally all node voltages can be found out by node analysis.
But how to find all node voltages if all currents in a circuit are known, otner than node analysis.

Comment: Define a convenient 0V reference point (= 'ground') and then use nodal analysis.

Comment: Okay well! But if there is  a method other than node analysis.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. In any case, a circuit might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If the currents in your circuit are known, just find the voltage drops to ground through any path.